# Clear the value of bootstrap-datepicker

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using bootstrap-datepicker from here: https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker

version: 2.3.2

I am having trouble to clear the date values of the datepicker when a button is clicked. I have checked the API but cannot find anything on clearing/resetting the datepicker. Any help is welcome

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use jQuery to clear the value of your date input.

For exemple with a button and a text input like this :

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
<button id="reset-date">Reset</button>
```

You can use the .val() function of jQuery.

```
$("#reset-date").click(function(){
    $('#datepicker').val("").datepicker("update");
})
```

Comment: This trick doesnt clear startdate endate limit,that was setting by setStartDate,setEndDate options

Comment: I think you can use setStartDate and setEndDate methods without parameters to clear limits. http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/methods.html#setstartdate

Comment: this is not the proper answer

Comment: This doesn't clear the date. You can check that with this on the console. `$("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate")` which still gives the previously selected date. You need to pipe `.datepicker('update')` to the end, as in the answer below.

Answer (score 35):

I was having similar trouble and the following worked for me:

```
$('#datepicker').val('').datepicker('update');
```

Both method calls were needed, otherwise it didn't clear.

Comment: This did the trick for me. Be aware that 'update' triggers another 'changeDate' event.

Comment: This is the better solution than the accepted one :)

Answer (score 29):

Current version 1.4.0 has [`clearBtn` option](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#clearbtn):

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    clearBtn: true
});
```

Besides adding button to interface it allows to delete value from input box manually.

Comment: This was `clearBtn: true` added to bring the clear button inside the date-picker right?

Comment: For some reason the styling for the clear button is broken for me.

Comment: Yes, That did for me..Thanks!

Comment: Unless I'm missing something you can't really use this to delete from the input box manually. Deleting the text does fire the 'clearDate' event, but the button fires both 'clearDate' and 'changeDate'. So the problem for me is that pressing the button triggers my event callback twice.

Answer (score 8):

I came across this thread while trying to clear the date already set.  Attempting:

```
$('#datepicker').val('').datepicker('update');
```

produced:

```
TypeError: t.dpDiv is undefined 
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js -- Line 8
```

Thinking that perhaps one needed to include the [original Datepicker for bootstrap](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) removes the error, but then causes the original Datepicker widget to appear! - so that's obviously wrong and not needed.

Looking further, the crash in jqueryui is in:

```
    /* Generate the date picker content. */
_updateDatepicker: function(inst) {
    this.maxRows = 4; //Reset the max number of rows being displayed (see #7043)
    datepicker_instActive = inst; // for delegate hover events
    inst.dpDiv.empty().append(this._generateHTML(inst));
    this._attachHandlers(inst);
```

and inst.pdDiv does not exist.

Investigating further - I realized that what was needed was:

```
        $formControl = $duedate.find("input");
        $formControl.val('');
        $formControl.removeData();
```

Which solved my problem.  Note I also needed the $formControl.removeData() otherwise the state of the widget would not be reinitialized to the initial state.

I hope this helps someone else. :-)

Comment: Hey, i have getting same error and also implemented same solution for this but cannot get success. is there any jquery/bootstrap version problem? and is there any specific block to put this code?

Comment: However if one tries to get date value like
var datevalue = $('#datepikcercontrol').data('date');
will still give the date value selected earlier

with above solution reading data this way worked for me

var datevalue = $("#datepikcercontrol").find("input").val();

Comment: This completely remove input field from DOM, and can't selecte daterange further

Comment: I was trying the same thing and getting the same error. This worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Actually it is much more useful use the method that came with the library like this `$(".datepicker").datepicker("clearDates");`

I recommend you to always take a look at the documentation of the library, here is the one I used for this.

[bootstrap-datepicker methods documentation](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/methods.html#cleardates)

Answer (score 5):

You can use this syntax to reset your bootstrap datepicker

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker('update','');
```

reference  http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/methods.html#update

Answer (score 1):

I know its too late to answer, but in my scenario below code was not working.

```
 $('#datepicker').val("");
 $('#datepicker').val('').datepicker('update');
 $('#datepicker').datepicker('update','');
```

here is my solution.

```
 $('#datepicker').val('').datepicker('remove').datepicker();
```

I did clear datepicker value first then removed datepicker and again reinitialize datepicker. its resolved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found the best anwser, it work for me.
Clear the value of bootstrap-datepicker:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', null);
```

Add value for boostrap-datepicker:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', datePicker);
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this thread while trying to figure out why the dates weren't being cleared in IE7/IE8.
It has to do with the fact that IE8 and older require a second parameter for the Array.prototype.splice() method.
Here's the original code in bootstrap.datepicker.js:

```
clear: function(){
    this.splice(0);
},
```

Adding the second parameter resolved my issue:

```
clear: function(){
    this.splice(0,this.length);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to do it in that way:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker('clearDates');
```