# unable to clear dates range in bootstrap datepicker input-daterange

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I've used the `input-daterange` of `Bootstrap datepicker` which is working fine.
But the problem is, I'm unable to clear the dates and the selection(range) in it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  datespicker();
});

function datespicker() {
  $('#data_5 .input-daterange').datepicker({
    keyboardNavigation: false,
    forceParse: false,
    autoclose: true
      //format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
  });
}

function ClearUsersStatistics() {
  $('#dtStartDate').val('');
  $('#dtEndDate').val('');

  //$('#datepicker').val('').datepicker('update');
  //$('#datepicker').val("");
  //$('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', null);

  //$("input[id$='dtStartDate'], input[id$='dtEndDate']").datepicker("option", "maxDate", null);
  //$("input[id$='dtStartDate'], input[id$='dtEndDate']").datepicker("option", "minDate", null);
}
```

```html
<link href="http://webapplayers.com/inspinia_admin-v2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://webapplayers.com/inspinia_admin-v2.0/css/plugins/jasny/jasny-bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://webapplayers.com/inspinia_admin-v2.0/css/plugins/datapicker/datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="http://webapplayers.com/inspinia_admin-v2.0/js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://webapplayers.com/inspinia_admin-v2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://webapplayers.com/inspinia_admin-v2.0/js/plugins/datapicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="http://webapplayers.com/inspinia_admin-v2.0/js/plugins/datapicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>


<div class="form-group" id="data_5">
  <label class="font-noraml">Range select</label>
  <div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
    <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="start" id="dtStartDate" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
    <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="end" id="dtEndDate" />
  </div>
</div>

<input class='btn btn-primary' id='Button1' value='Clear Statistics' onclick='ClearUsersStatistics();' type='button' />
```

As you can see on the snippet, I'm only able to clear the text on the date-pickers, but the selection range inside the date-pickers is not clearing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: As I only noticed afterwards you already tried `.datepicker('update')`, you want to take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22196162/clear-the-value-of-bootstrap-datepicker).

Comment: Did you find a solution? I've been struggling to reset an `input-daterange` but nothing seems to work :/

Comment: nope :( 
I've used some third party controls

Answer (score 2):

They seemed to have addressed/resolved this:
http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/markup.html#date-range

> Note that that input-daterange itself does not implement the datepicker` methods. Methods should be directly called to the inputs. For example:

```
$(‘.input-daterange input’).each(function (){
    $(this).datepicker(“clearDates”);

});
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. This method worked for me. I actually used `$('.input-daterange input[type="text"]').datepicker('clearDates')` because I added an `input-group-btn` to my page and it was pulling that in as an input too.

Answer (score 1):

You probably gonna have to trigger `.datepicker('update');` too.

```
$('#dtStartDate').add('#dtEndDate').val('').datepicker('update');
```