# Clear Bootstrap DatePicker Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using the [Bootstrap DatePicker control](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) in my app. I am trying to figure out how to clear the value of the field. I feel kind of dumb asking about this. To be honest, it seems like it should be straightforward. But, I've been unsuccessful. I have tried the approaches recommend in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22196162/clear-the-value-of-bootstrap-datepicker) without luck.

Currently, I have [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rraz2yq3/1/). My code in question looks like the following:

```
$(function() {
  $('#birthday').datetimepicker({ showTodayButton: true });
  $('#getDateButton').on('click', function() {
    var selectedDate = $('#birthday').data('date');
    if (selectedDate) {
      selectedDate = selectedDate.format('MM-DD-YYYY');
    }
    $('#formattedDate').html(selectedDate);
  });

  $('#clearButton').on('click', function() {
    alert('Clear the value in the "birthday" field...');
    $('#birthday').data('clear');
    // what now?
  });
});
```

It's like the functions in the control don't work. Or, the documentation is incorrect. As the fiddle shows, my "Get Date" function is not working either. That's why I feel like something is really wrong. Am I missing something or misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `#birthday` contains the datepicker, do this and it will work:

```
$('#clearButton').on('click', function() {
    alert('Clear the value in the "birthday" field...');
    $('#birthday').data("DateTimePicker").clear();
  });
```

You need to call [clear](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#clear) on the `$('#birthday').data("DateTimePicker")` object. Function calls are illustrated [here](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#linked-pickers).

To get the date, do this:

```
$('#getDateButton').on('click', function() {
    var selectedDate = $('#birthday').data('DateTimePicker').date();

    if (selectedDate) {
      selectedDate = selectedDate.format('MM-DD-YYYY');
      console.log("selected date "+ selectedDate);
    }
    $('#formattedDate').html(selectedDate);
  });
```

Comment: @ZachTempleton added information on how to get the date

Comment: Thanks for your help. I feel pretty dumb :). I was doing this: `$('#birthday').data('date')` and this `$('#birthday').data('clear')` I even went to: `$('#birthday').data('clear').FUNCTION()`

Comment: Or @ZachTempleton you can simply do by this : **`$('#birthday').datepicker('setStartDate', null);`**

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work with this [code](https://jsfiddle.net/rraz2yq3/3/):

```
$('#clearButton').on('click', function() {
    alert('Clear the value in the "birthday" field...');
    $('#birthdayDate').val('');
    // what now?
})
```

Answer (score 0):

this is ok
`$('#birthday').data("DateTimePicker").clear();`

you can see this http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/
http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#clear

> Note All functions are accessed via the data attribute e.g. $('#datetimepicker').data("DateTimePicker").FUNCTION()

Comment: Wow! I feel really dumb. I was trying `$('#datetimepicker').data("clear").FUNCTION()`. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: add the required reference to import:

`import { bla-bla-bla, NgbInputDatepicker } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';`

Step 2: reference it as ViewChild:

`@ViewChild('lastStartMinDatepicker') lastStartMinDatepicker: NgbInputDatepicker;`

considering you have something like this in the markup:

```
<input
   #lastStartMinDatepicker="ngbDatepicker"
   #thisElement="ngModel"
   ngbDatepicker
   (click)="lastStartMinDatepicker.toggle()"
   class="form-control"
   [class.is-invalid]="thisElement.invalid && thisElement.touched"
   [(ngModel)]="lastStartMinPicker"
   [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }"
   placeholder="Date From"
   readonly
/>
```

Step 3: remove value from it:

`this.lastStartMinDatepicker.writeValue(null);`

Step 4: enjoy :)